# Writing integration tests for Cassandra in Python

Tags: python, cassandra, integration-testing

For a project we're using Cassandra in a Python project. Is there any way of doing integration tests for this? e.g. running an embedded Cassandra instance?

Comment: Typically integration testing is done against a real service, meaning you'd run a local cassandra on the integration testing machine and run your tests against that. The tests should be idempotent, ie create DBs and schemas and wipe them per test or test suite.

Comment: Correct. You should take a look at CCM. It allows you to create and start a local cassandra cluster and you can use its python API. You can also look at the cassandra python driver since it has integration tests as well. https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm , https://github.com/datastax/python-driver

Comment: CCM is also how C* integration tests are run, see https://github.com/riptano/cassandra-dtest and should work for what your trying to do